# Where dependencies and services should register when using Web API and Azure Function under same solution in Clean Architecture

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-functions, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API solution that is implemented based on Clean Architecture. Further down application using Entity Framework Core 7 in the infrastructure layer. My app dependencies and services are registered in `Program.cs` of the Web API project.

Now I need a time-triggered Azure Function and I am trying see the best option going forward to register dependencies as it should be in Web API or in the Azure Function?

The Web API and Azure function are in same project/solution. Is that OK from an architecture point of view to repeat dependencies based on services usage under Web API and Azure Function?

Another option I was thinking of: call Web API from Azure Function but then it kills the very purpose of service less?

[image]

Comment: An Azure Function is **server-less** - not "service less" ....

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail ?  Because Azure Function and Web API has different hosting model. Why you keep both in same project as Azure function has different life cycle then API.

Comment: where I put my back-end logic 'domain, application and infrastructure` where is expected to used by both API and Azure Function

Comment: I have upload the app architecture